# AngularJS nested Controllers reload inside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’m struggling with how best to architect an AngularJS application to eliminate nested child Controllers from looping inside of its parents ng-repeat. Other than a Ben Nadel’s blog post I cannot seem to find a solid answer.

**BACKGROUND** 
*(Parent -> child nested controllers)*

In the example below and in Plunker I have two controllers. A parent ArticlesCtrl and a nested child CommentsCtrl that is nested inside of a ArticlesCtrl ng-repeat loop.

**ISSUE** 
*(child controller reloads if inside of ng-repeat loop)*

Given this nested structure the CommentsCtrl will load for each article in the articles array. So if I have n articles I end up with CommentsCtrl loading n times. This is a problem as numerous modules will complain that an existing instance of an module already exists.

**2 POTENTIAL SOLUTIONS** 
*(Uber Controller OR peer based controllers with services)*

*Option 1 - easier approach of the two*: create an Uber "thick" ArticlesCtrl and use services to offload as much logic as possible e.g CommentService, ImageService, DocumentService, etc.  The issue here is even if I keep a pure view controller relation with all application logic in the services I potentially end up with a fairly large controller. This also ends up breaking many of the S.O.L.I.D principles as you now start inject Poll, Documents, Images, Chart, etc. and starts to morph to become a "ContentCtroller instead".

*Option 2*: move the child controller to sibling controllers i.e. Article and Comments at the same level and then manage relationship state e.g comments as child of article using services? The issue with that approach is you end up with some overhead and potentially lose some the ease of backend DB relations e.g. inLaravel and other backend code you would create a query with relationships which returns a nested data model. With the sibling / peer based I would need to parse out the nested data to separate Angular services

**QUESTION**: 
Am I doing something wrong or missing an alternative strategy / approach? Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DXHd6H?p=preview

HTML

```
  <body>
    <ul class="article-container" ng-controller="ArticlesCtrl">
      <li class="article" ng-repeat="article in articles track by article.id">
        <h3>article from ng-repeat  : ID:  {{ article.id }}    title: {{ article.title }}</h3>
        <div class="comment-ctrl" ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
          <p class="comment-detail">$scope.comment {{ comment }} AND $scope.counting{{ counting }}</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

**JS 1.4.8**

```
angular.module('articles', ['comments']);
angular.module('comments', []);

(function () {

  'use strict';

  ArticlesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function ArticlesCtrl ($scope) {
      $scope.articles = [
          {'id' : 1, 'title' : 'Article 1' },
          {'id' : 2, 'title' : 'Article 2' },
          {'id' : 3, 'title' : 'Article 3'}
        ];
  }

  CommentsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'CounterFactory'];
  function CommentsCtrl ($scope, CounterFactory) {

      $scope.comment = "$scope.comment";
      $scope.counting = CounterFactory.counter();
  }

  CounterFactory.$inject = [];
  function CounterFactory () {
      var service = this,
          counter = 1;

      service.counter = function() {
        return counter++;
      }
      return {
          counter:function () {
            return service.counter();
          }
      }
  }

  angular
    .module('articles')
    .controller('ArticlesCtrl', ArticlesCtrl);

  angular
    .module('comments')
    .controller('CommentsCtrl', CommentsCtrl)
    .factory('CounterFactory', CounterFactory);

})();
```

Comment: this is a good candidate for turning the child controller/elements into a directive with an isolated scope, but even as a directive, you will always have an instance of the nested controller for each iteration.

Comment: @Claies that seems to be very logical i.e. ArticlesCtrl + content directives + directive services. The only issue I see is that I might end up with a bloated module, but to your point isolated scopes plus imbedded directive controllers as needed would still be a clean structure. Unless I hear anything different I'm going to pursue your approach. Thanks for the insight.